# Visual Studio Find All Not Referenced

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio is there an automatic way to search over file(s) and find all classes/properties/methods that aren't referenced. Essentially abandoned code.

I don't want to manually have to right click on each and select "Find All References"

Comment: I don't believe there is.

Comment: Don't tell me that! ;)

Comment: Resharper offers this IIRC.

Comment: So nothing out of the box. Could I write a script to do it via VS?

Comment: @aherrick You could probably use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get List of Zero Reference Codes in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974433/get-list-of-zero-reference-codes-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of Visual Studio in the current version. Using Roslyn you could code and Inspector yourself, but [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) doesn't offer one out of the box either at the moment. The walk-through on [Semantic analysis](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=263973) should get you started. The [roslyn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/home?forum=roslyn) is a good place to seek help or find examples, and there's a well [monitored tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roslyn) as well of course.

Productivity plugins like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [Code Rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/) offer this for sure. There are other similar tools that might have this feature [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx), [VisualAssist](http://www.wholetomato.com/), [CodeItRight](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx) are likely candidates.

You can also use something like [Visual NDepend](http://ndepend.com/Default.aspx) to detect unused methods. Their new command [Linq to Code](http://ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) features should make it relatively easy to build a commandline tool that fishes out all unused calls.

Comment: Hmm I'd hate to have to reinvent the wheel here. This has to have been done already. Strange it isn't built into VS seems like a huge win.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if you install SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) this also add grayed reference count to each method in visual studio.
Note: This is actually "code lens" which is no longer available for VS2015. Installing the SSDT is the way you can have "code lens" in VS2015.