# Search for methods/classes/properties with 0 references in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I love the feature in VS 2015 that shows the amount of references on top of properties/methods/classes.

But I was wondering if there is actually a way to search for all the properties/methods/classes that have 0 references.

Comment: If you can use Roslyn you should be able to do it with SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. I was actually wondering if there is an option for this in VS itself. But thanks for the answer, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I know its possible using the interactive window (and the Roslyn API) but I'm not well versed in that. May want to try asking a question specific to using that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get List of Zero Reference Codes in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974433/get-list-of-zero-reference-codes-in-visual-studio)