# Find "Dead code"

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I am trying to find private methods that are not called from any other code (CA1811) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182264(v=vs.110).aspx, with Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis buy it doesn't detect it, despite putting the project code analysis rule set in "*all rules*". This is possible? In this case, how can I configure my project solution? In case of installing any extension, I will prefer that it was free. Thanks!

Comment: You need ReSharper with Solution Wide Analysis

Comment: Upgrade to VS2015. This indicates the number of references to each method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule [CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182264(v=vs.110).aspx) perfectly works fine to detect the uncalled private methods.

To enable the code analysis warnings, you also need to set this value in project properties like this -

[image]

As a suggestion it is good idea to have our custom ruleset, to have more control over rule violations for example you can define any violation as error, so that you can get it as compile error and fix it.

Comment: I did not know that you can custom ruleset. Thanks.

Comment: This answer to a similar question has more rules for detecting dead code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37579734/350372

Comment: This doesn't work.  I dont' have any "Rule Set" dropdown in this config page, and the "Configuration" and "Platform" dropdowns are disabled.  Down-voted.

Answer (score 10):

In case you are OK with a command line utility, I suggest the [Resharper Command Line tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html). It can do many great things that will help you, including finding dead code. It's free (Resharper VS extension is not) so it will get you going.

If Resharper can't find any dead code, maybe there's none and Code Analysis does work :-)