# List unreferenced files in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have been experimenting a lot inside a solution containing only **.NET Core 3.1** projects, and I noticed that there was a lot of unnecessary/unused code as a result.

#### Is there a way to list all the code inside my solution that isn't referenced anywhere else?

I'm aware that Visual Studio 2019 has the CodeLens feature that shows *if* a piece of code is referenced, but checking it for every single file manually is obviously not what I'm going for.

In existing answers for older versions of Visual Studio, the [FxCop tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/bb429476(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is mentioned a lot but as you can see on the Microsoft Page, it's no longer being updated. I also tried to run [Code Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019#code-analysis-solution-property-page) on my solution, but since I couldn't configure the analysis parameters for my solution, that didn't lead anywhere either. I even tried to configure code analysis on the project level, but Visual Studio didn't recognize my project as a candidate for analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RuleSet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579734/4364057) to make your CodeAnalysis show you unused code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Dead Code Rules" Description=" " ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="CA1801" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="CA1804" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="CA1811" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="CA1812" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="CA1823" Action="Warning" />
  </Rules>
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.NativeCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Native">
    <Rule Id="C6259" Action="Warning" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

<s>Edit: You can use [this step by step guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/biswapinky/remove-unused-codedead-code-using-visual-studio/) to build your RuleSet.</s>

Edit 2: Since the step by step guide is outdated, here is a new way of activating the needed rules:

1. Go to the properties page of your project (right click -> Properties)
2. Go to "Code Analysis", the last tab
3. Click "Configure"
4. Enter "unused" and activate all the rules that you want
5. On the right, optionally set the Action to "Error" for extra attention
6. Save (ctrl+s)

**Edit 3:** We will keep the ruleset but it turns out I had an old project and on new ones, you need to do the following:

1. If your target framework is below .NET5, install <s>Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers</s> `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` from NuGet (*FxCop was deprecated*)
2. If you haven't already, add a file `.editorconfig` to you solution
3. Enable the rules you want like this:

   `[*.cs]`
   `# Avoid unused private fields`
   `dotnet_diagnostic.CA1823.severity = error`

in the editorconfig file to activate them.

Comment: My project properties view looks [like this](https://imgur.com/a/IxQZi09), the configurations bit is greyed out.

Comment: Turns out my information was outdated again, so I updated it again.

Comment: The third approach worked! The only problem now is that most of my "unused" classes actually have internal references to constructors, so I'm still stuck manually filtering through my files.

Comment: Try getting the Jetbrains.Annotations NuGet package and annotate those with [UsedImplicitely] and hope VS can actually use these annotations without ReSharper installed.

Comment: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers has been deprecated and replaced with  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers#microsoftcodeanalysisnetanalyzers) which is the default for .NET 5+ projects and can be enabled for previous versions; follow details on the github page.

Comment: The example in the third solution "dotnet_diagnostic.CA1822.severity = error" may be misleading as it doesn't fix the problem the OP described.  CA1822: is used to "Mark members as static"

Comment: So now almost 2 years later I actually saw this comment and edited my answer, turns out I wanted 1823 (Avoid unused private fields) instead of 1822.