# How to find and remove unused keys from ResourceManager in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resourcemanager

I have a project with a lot of ResourceManagers, each containing a lot of keys. Some of these keys are not used, so I want to remove them.

How can I find and remove unused keys from a `ResourceManager` in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974433/how-to-get-list-of-zero-reference-unreferenced-code-in-visual-studio

Comment: When we use IStringLocalizer or IHtmlLocalizer in ASP.net Core, none of the keys point anywhere, so this solution doesn't work!